# C# Keep CPU at/near designated percent usage for testing purposes

Tags: c#, testing, cpu, throttling

I am currently working on a little in-house testing app to create multiple types of load on the computer so that we can see how our software works under load.  I am getting hung up on one request, in that I make some sort of way to specify a percent usage of the CPU (say, 40%) before the user runs the program, and that will hopefully keep the cpu in a range +-10% of what they put in.  I've been told that they had seen programs doing it before, but every one that I had seen that claimed to do so did not work.  I am attempting to read an average usage and sleep the thread running so that the CPU usage lowers, but I have found that is not accurate.  It is also going to be used on multiple servers, each with different CPUs, so I can't do very much hard coding as it will need to work on each server.  I personally do not think its possible to accurately do, but I'm asking here as a last ditch effort to see if anyone else has come across software similar to this, and knows how it would be written.

Edit: I have attempted to use a lower priority thread, and was also told that would not be useful to them (though I had the option created just for the purpose of testing before this was requested of me).

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to cap how much CPU power you can consume, that is the task of the OS, determine the scheduling; other than limiting how many cores it can use. What you can do is alter the priority of the process, I was also going to mention sleeping it, but you've already noted that that is an imperfect solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We did something analogous a while back tuning an application server.  We found that our overall throughput was best when the CPU was around 70%.  Our solution was to spin up additional threads, with a delay between each one, until the desired load was reached.  If CPU went above 80%, we reduced the number of running threads (signaled a thread to finish its current work and then terminate).  If CPU dropped below 60%, we fired up a new thread.

You could apply similar logic to create artificial load that you can tune to a target CPU utilization.  Your threads would need to balance CPU and non-CPU (IO, or just sleep) in order to allow for fine tuning.  If your threads are very CPU intensive, each will consume 1 CPU core to about 100%.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what did your thread look like?  Currently I just have mine doing a constant addition and subtraction in an infinite loop, and that eats up an entire core on its own (though the machine I'm working on at the moment isn't very powerful)

Comment: @BillyGallon, Infinite CPU bound loop will eat 100% of a core on any machine (unless OS level scheduling will not schedule that thread either due to priority or other limits i.e. as suggested by usr)

Comment: The threads in our case did real-world work, selecting data from a DB table and then performing calculations on it.  I suspect that interspersing Thread.Sleep calls (sleep for random but fairly short intervals) with CPU intensive calculations should allow you to create a thread that averages modest CPU utilization so that you have reasonable ability to control the overall load generated by a number of threads.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Windows 8 you can make the OS scheduler [cap the CPU usage using Windows Jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).